# How to add <hr> tags between unique rows from query resultset?

Tags: php, html, arrays, grouping

I'm trying to add an `<hr>` tag between lines when a new name is encountered.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$rs = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");

$info = [];
$i = 0;
while($rows = $rs->fetch_array()) {
    $info[$i]["pass"] = $rows["pass"];
    $info[$i]["name"] = $rows["name_real"];
    $i++;
}
// I want to print a line just after the last duplicated value
for($i = 0; $i < count($info) - 1; $i++) {
    if($info[$i]["name"] !== $info[$i +1]["name"] && // some duplicate condition) {
        $info[$i]["line"] = "<hr>";
    };
}
```

This is the structure of my `info` array build from the resultset.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [pass] => 12
        [name] => Martin
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [pass] => 20
        [name] => Martin
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [pass] => 2
        [name] => Martin
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [pass] => 2
        [name] => Alberto
    )
)
```

My desired result would be something like:

```
<p>Martin<p>
<p>Martin<p>
<p>Martin<p>
<hr>
<p>Alberto<p>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Dekel Hello!, I've tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438140/find-duplicate-value-in-multi-dimensional-array/18438311#18438311 and the rest of the answers but doesnt seem to work for me :/

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221390/php-count-duplicate-values-within-two-dimensional-array-then-display-only-uni)

Comment: Write the code that you tried as part of the question

Comment: @Matt but I don't want to remove anything..

Comment: You don't need to? Use the accepted answer to get a count. If count > 1 then return true else false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with just one loop.  First, use your mysqli query to order the resultset by `name_real`. (If you are only going to use `name_real`, you can change the SELECT clause to reflect this. I have shown this in the commented query.)  Then write a condition that checks for a new/unique `name_real` -- if so, echo `<hr>`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04abd249e9c823b06373bf1f7d924310bd8421f4))

```
//$rs = $conn->query("SELECT `name_real` FROM usuarios ORDER BY `name_real`;");
$rs=[
    ['pass'=>2,'name_real'=>'Alberto'],
    ['pass'=>12,'name_real'=>'Martin'],
    ['pass'=>20,'name_real'=>'Martin'],
    ['pass'=>2,'name_real'=>'Martin']
];

$prev=NULL;
//while($rows = $rs->fetch_array()) {
foreach($rs as $rows){
    if($prev && $rows['name_real']!=$prev){  // if not first iteration, and new name_real
        echo "<hr>";
    }
    echo "<p>{$rows['name_real']}</p>";
    $prev=$rows['name_real'];  // preserve this value for next iteration's check
}
```

Output:

```
<p>Alberto</p>
<hr>
<p>Martin</p>
<p>Martin</p>
<p>Martin</p>
```

Comment: Hello and If i wanted to add the hr just after the duplicated values ? see my desired result for example, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Madtin That is exactly what my method does.  The reason that my posted result doesn't literally match your posted result is because I arbitrarily ordered the names in the array ASC.  See this [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5129890fcc320e14951e70a085ae8424fdc23328) where I have 6 rows and 3 unique names and the hr's come between each set.

Comment: Yes but what If i had the array like this ! [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2311256f1bb45d6cea47e6d88edc386534a1684a) and i wanted the hr on the after the duplicated martin aswell ?

Comment: @Madtin Okay, simple, just manually add `echo "<hr>";` after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care what the duplicate names are or how many duplicates exist, and you just want to see whether or not there are any, it looks like it could be simpler code than some of the possible duplicate answers.

Get the names

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name');
```

Then check if the full list of names is equal to the unique list.

```
$has_duplicates = $names != array_unique($names);
```

---

<sub>Disclaimer: This answer looks odd now. It was provided for [Revision 1 of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45579282/1). I seem to have misunderstood the question somewhat, and then Revision 2 transformed it to the extent that this answer no longer applies at all. Still, I think it's a useful way to do the thing that it seemed was trying to be done at first.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This solution would be handy:

```
$result = array();
$names = array_count_values(array_column($source, 'name'));
foreach($names as $key=>$val) {
    $result[$key] = ($val == 1 ? false : true);
}
```