# PHP How to count duplicate values in 2D array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have this array:

```
Array ( [55118] => Array ( [id] => 55118 
                           [usr_name] => Name 1
                           [usr_employment] => Fulltime
                         )
        [55179] => Array ( [id] => 55179
                           [usr_name] => Name 2
                           [usr_employment] => Fulltime
                         )
        [55549] => Array ( [id] => 55549
                           [usr_name] => Name 1
                           [usr_employment] => Fulltime
                         )
      )
```

Now 'd like to count how many times "Name 1" exist in my array.
My problem is that it's a 2D array.

So i'd like to print:

Name 1, 2 times
Name 2, 1 time

**I can't find a correct answer to this question before.**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948946

Comment: Please tell me why downvote so i can prevent this in the future!

Comment: Not the downvoter but possibly downvoted because this is a commonly asked question

Comment: @BjörnC I didn't down-vote but it would be considered a duplicate. Just do a bit more searching first before posting.

Comment: Because most likely the person that downvoted thinks that you didn't provide the solution you have tried as a minimal code, or specific errors

Comment: Don"t worry about downvote, this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221390/php-count-duplicate-values-within-two-dimensional-array-then-display-only-uni

Comment: @PraveenKumar No. I only wan't to count the duplicates. Not remove them!

Comment: @Pogrindis You guys are so fast marking it as a duplicate. Your Link will remove all duplicates. I'd just wana count them!

Comment: @BjörnC so you can do compare of the two when you have removed from another instance, there are several solutions to the problem, the speed of the duplicate is on the right hand sidebar, there are **related** questions. These usually show duplicates.

Comment: Well, a foreach can make what you do no? Or you want to use a php array function?

Comment: Try this:

    foreach($yourArray as $key => $value){
        $newArr[] = $value['usr_name'];
    }
    $counts = array_count_values($newArr);
    foreach($counts as $name => $count){
        echo $name." - ".$count." times<br>"
    }

Comment: I don't know why people marks a question as a duplicate when the anwser of the duplicate are not the same as the question...people read a little before flag a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($arr, "usr_name"));
```

This should give you an associative array with key being the name and the value being the count of that name.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Comment: who is the intelligent person downvoted the answer

Comment: @Pogrindis probably because someone didn't like the question. It seems to happen quite often, someone just clicks all the downbuttons there is without reading.